# Image inside a link that has a color overlay on hover

Tags: html, css

I need to make an image inside a link and it should have a color overlay on hover with a text inside it that's in dead center. But I don't know how. I know how to make a simple color overlay over an image, but how to do this with an img inside a ?

This is my code so far and as you can see, it's not what I want to make. Can someone help me out with this one?

```css
.img-overlay img {
    position: relative;
  }
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(41,42,44,0.5);
}
.img-overlay {
    position: relative;
}
.img-overlay:hover .overlay {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-overlay">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">
    <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My image needs to be inside a , so that it's clickable and leads to somewhere. How can I achieve this?

Comment: why not just use a background image on our a?

Comment: _"My image needs to be inside a"_ - so, start by replacing the outer `div` with an `a` ... And centering stuff via CSS in all thinkable situations and combinations is a topic that has been discussed so broadly already that you should be able to solve that part yourself with a little bit of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the container `inline-block` so it fits to the size of the image, set the image to `vertical-align: top` so the white space at the bottom is gone, then use `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on the overlay container to center it's contents.

```css
.img-overlay img {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(41, 42, 44, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-overlay:hover .overlay {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<a class="img-overlay">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">
    <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

You might also toggle `opacity` on `:hover` so you can `transition` the change.

```css
.img-overlay img {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(41, 42, 44, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-overlay:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="img-overlay">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="overlay">
    <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Ohhh! This makes sense! Finally. Thank you, Michael. I just replaced the first div with an a and that was it. Again, thanks!

Comment: @hemoglobin oh oops, I missed that part about you wanting it to be a link. Yeah, just changing the tag should work. Updated my answer to reflect that. And you're welcome :)